# Cannot call value of non-function type 'ViewRouter

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am copying a project from a website to understand navigation in swiftUI. I believe I've copied the code correctly but end up getting an error when I compile.

The three relevant files are:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MotherView: View {
    var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct MotherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MotherView(viewRouter: ViewRouter())
    }
}
```

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class ViewRouter {
    var currentView: Int = 0
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    var viewRouter = ViewRouter()
    
    var body: some View {
        MotherView(viewRouter: viewRouter)
    }
}
```

When I compile I get an error saying "Cannot call value of non-function type 'ViewRouter'" and it offers the "fix" of removing the () brackets from the end of ViewRouter instantiation which obviously doesn't work.

My code appears to be the same as the example given in the article and it seems clear to me that I want to create an instance of ViewRouter and pass it to MotherView but the tool appears to get confused.

I've seen many other questions about this error but never with the preview which makes me think I'm doing something obviously wrong but I can not see it. Has anybody had to deal with this?

Comment: I have just tried this code in a Playground and it works just fine. does not give me any errors. Try restarting Xcode and cleaning build folder with `cmd + shirt + k`

Comment: It is not in provided code. There is either type duplication conflict (some other ViewRouter) or broken project. Would you elaborate more to provide details?

Comment: Ah restarting Xcode did solved the issue. Tools getting confused. Thanks.